# Detecting multiple sessions from same user on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, user-management

I am writing an application which uses the Google user API and anyone having a google account can login. I would want to prevent from multiple users using the same google account to login simultaneously. Basically, I would like to allow only 1 user / account to be using my application. As I am running a subscription service, I need to restrict users sharing accounts and simultaneously logging in.

Can I accomplish this somehow in App Engine using Users module? If not, can someone please suggest an alternate mechanism?

I am using Python on App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you'll have to build the session tracking functionality yourself.